# Google Web Core Vitals - management, how to in wordpress and advice

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, admin, google

I maintain several small websites and know my CSS and HTML. However, when it comes to javascript and server side optimisation, I have no idea.

I was advised to ask my question here where I initially placed it on Stackoverflow.

I'd be grateful for some feedback on what to do to fix my page speed insights. A step by step perhaps and how. I'd prefer to optimise the sites myself and I'm not sure how to do this or where to start.

I've been advised that I should stay away from plugins to speed up wordpress websites.

We do not need CDN as all the websites are focussed on clients in our own country.

1. Our ISP has a good server so server config isn't a problem that I am aware of.
2. Wordpress Administration: I have several plugins to optimise images and compress css etc but apparently the wordpress core already does this?
3. GZIP support apparently can be enabled via 1 line of code `update_option( 'gzipcompression', 1 )` **but where do I put this?**
4. Our wordpress theme is DIVI.  Not the fastest.  Perhaps I should change the theme on all sites?

Many thanks for your suggestions and advice in advance.

Comment: Can you link to the stackoverflow question? Questions here need to be specific but this isn't phrased as a question, it's phrased as a discussion. You need a single specific question that can be answered with facts, worded in a way that you can mark an answer as the correct solution/answer, not just the best reply. Remember, 3rd party plugins and themes are off topic here and not in this stacks scope

Comment: I've removed the request for plugin recommendations for webp as that's off topic here, and theme recommendations are off topic too, that leaves 4 questions possibly 3, you should ask 4 separate questions rather than 1 single question that has multiple questions inside it. Anybody interested in writing an answer cannot unless they can answer all 4 questions, which reduces the chances of you getting responses. If you're wanting recommendations you should ask on the software recommendations stack

Comment: Thanks very much Tom.  I will ask in 4 separate questions.  I appreciate your time to explain the rules. :-)  many thanks.